# How do I override rw-r--r-- root/wheel for a all files in a directory?

Tags: command-line, permissions, rm

I am trying to delete a directory on OS X. I do `rm -r /path/dir` but I keep getting many, many messages like this:

```
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for cron/migrate.php?
```

I type y for one message, but then another one pops up. I would like to override the message for the whole directory in one command. How do I do that?

Comment: Step 1: `brew install git` Step 2: `brew link git` or `brew link --overwrite git` Step 3: `git version` Enjoy the latest git version on macOS.

Comment: Pretty sure the march of time has rendered the answers here incorrect. I should note that, at time of asking, the answers above were probably correct, but several years on, that is no longer true. For a better answer in 2022, go to AskDifferent, and ignore all the hand-waving non-answers and see the reply on Nov 6, 2015 at 15:44 by prosseek. [Delete unnecessary files in /System/Library for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214540)

Answer (score 27):

First approach is, using `-f` option for `rm` command:

`rm -rf /your/path`

Second approach is,

`yes | rm -r /your/path`

First approach used more for your purpose and second approach used more for **copy or moving** files.

Comment: wow, I finally learned why the "repeat" command is called `yes`!

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-f` flag to `rm`

```
rm -rf /path/dir
```

This wont ask you any questions, anything that you can delete will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to delete files that don't belong to you is to do it as root.

```
sudo rm -R /path/to/dir
```

This overcomes most permissions that cause the override prompt. There can still be times when permissions are set to prevent root accidentally deleting files at which time preceding the rm command with `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir` can be helpful.

Remember that you need to be sure you want to delete the files and that your path is correct.

Comment: this needs the account to be registered in `/etc/sudoers` - which is one of the brakes that should prevent users from doing what they shouldn't do. Otherwise, thankfully!, this would be pretty useless!

Comment: The user mentions being on OSX - a user account with admin privileges on OSX has access to sudo without modifying sudoers. If he didn't have an admin account he shouldn't be able to delete files owned by root by saying yes to override.